# Spring JUnit test keeps return nullpointerexception on my service class

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

**UPDATE 25-11-2012**

Hi it seems that my context files was in the wrong 'classpath' They had to be in the test classpath. I solved this by adding a folder called resources to the src/test/ folder. In here I could put my application contexts. I have also removed the @TestExecutionListeners from the test. I also needed to add some dependencies to my pom file for javax/servlet/serlvetException and such. If anyone is interested my code can be seen at [Github](https://github.com/martin-rohwedder/MROBlog/tree/issue9), under the branch issue9.

---

**Question [Solved]**

I have made a simple application, by using spring 3. I have made a service class which uses a DAO class to map things to and from the database, by using the simple JDBC template.

My problem is when i am trying to make an integration test on these classes, it return a NullPointerException (See Stacktrace). It is really annoying since I can't seem to find the answer, so I hope you guys can help me out. Below I have posted all my different files.

**Stacktrace**

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.115 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(dk.martinrohwedder.blog.test.ArticleServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
at dk.martinrohwedder.blog.service.ArticleService.getFiveLastArticles(ArticleService.java:30)
at dk.martinrohwedder.blog.test.ArticleServiceTest.test(ArticleServiceTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

**ArticleServiceTest**

```
package dk.martinrohwedder.blog.test;

import dk.martinrohwedder.blog.domain.Article;
import dk.martinrohwedder.blog.service.ArticleService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
/**
 *
 * @author Martin Rohwedder
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test-context.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class ArticleServiceTest {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ArticleService articleService;

    //private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        //db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).setName("blog").addScript("classpath:create-db.sql").addScript("classpath:test-data.sql").build();
        //articleService.getArticleDao().setDataSource(db);
        //articleService = new ArticleService();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        //articleService.getArticleDao().setDataSource(null);
        //db.shutdown();
        //articleService = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = articleService.getFiveLastArticles();

        int number = articles.size();
        assertEquals(3, number);
    }

}
```

**ArticleService**

```
package dk.martinrohwedder.blog.service;

import dk.martinrohwedder.blog.domain.Article;
import dk.martinrohwedder.blog.repository.ArticleDao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
/**
 *
 * @author Martin Rohwedder
 * @since 22-11-2012
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Service("articleService")
public class ArticleService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ArticleDao articleDao;

    public ArticleDao getArticleDao() {
        return articleDao;
    }

    public void setArticleDao(ArticleDao articleDao) {
        this.articleDao = articleDao;
    }

    public ArrayList<Article> getFiveLastArticles()
    {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = (ArrayList) articleDao.selectAllArticles();

        if (articles.size() > 5) {
            articles = (ArrayList) articles.subList(articles.size() - 6, articles.size());
        }

        return articles;
    }

}
```

**ArticleDao**

```
package dk.martinrohwedder.blog.repository;

import dk.martinrohwedder.blog.domain.Article;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
/**
 *
 * @author Martin Rohwedder
 * @since 22-11-2012
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Repository
public class ArticleDao implements IArticleDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> selectAllArticles() {
        String sql = "select article_id, headline from article";
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ArticleMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public Article selectArticle(int articleId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void insertArticle(Article article) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateArticle(Article article) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteArticle(int articleId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    /**
     * Article Mapper is responsible for map all rows found in a sql 
     * statement to Article objects.
     */
    private static final class ArticleMapper implements RowMapper<Article> {

        @Override
        public Article mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.setId(rs.getInt("article_id"));
            article.setHeadline(rs.getString("headline"));

            return article;
        }

    }

}
```

**test-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dk.martinrohwedder.blog" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="embeddedDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:blog"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL"/>
        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="embeddedDataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:create-db.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

**create-db.sql**

```
create database if not exists blog;

use blog;

drop table if exists article;

create table article
(
    article_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    headline varchar(30) not null,
    primary key (article_id)
);
```

**test-data.xml**

```
insert into article (article_headline)
values ("Artikel 1");
insert into article (article_headline)
values ("Artikel 2");
insert into article (article_headline)
values ("Artikel 3");
```

Both test-context.xml, create-db.sql and test-data.sql is in the classpath since they are in the package called Other Sources (src/main/resources).

Hopes that anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using
  `<context:annotation-config/>`
instead of
`<mvc:annotation-driven />`
in your test-context.xml file.

`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is a tag added in Spring 3.0 which does the following:

1. Configures the Spring 3 Type ConversionService (alternative to
   PropertyEditors)
2. Adds support for formatting Number fields with @NumberFormat
3. Adds support for formatting Date, Calendar, and Joda Time fields with @DateTimeFormat, if Joda Time is on the classpath
4. Adds support for validating @Controller inputs with @Valid, if a JSR-303 Provider is on the classpath
5. Adds support for support for reading and writing XML, if JAXB is on the classpath (HTTP message conversion with @RequestBody/@ResponseBody)
6. Adds support for reading and writing JSON, if Jackson is o n the classpath (along the same lines as #5)

`<context:annotation-config/>`
Looks for annotations on beans in the same application context it is defined and declares support for all the general annotations like @Autowired, @Resource, @Required, @PostConstruct etc etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that when I get home, I am at a friends house atm. :)

Comment: Hi it seems that my context files was in the wrong 'classpath' They had to be in the test classpath. I solved this by adding a folder called resources to the src/test/ folder. In here I could put my application contexts. I have also removed the @TestExecutionListeners from the test. I also needed to add some dependencies to my pom file for javax/servlet/serlvetException and such. If anyone is interested my code can be seen at [Github](https://github.com/martin-rohwedder/MROBlog/tree/issue9), under the branch issue9. And it also worked with annotation-config tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `articleDao` is not being set. If you want to use a Spring bean in the test then you can't instantiate the service in your test. Take this line out...

```
articleService = new ArticleService();
```

Comment: I removed it now... Sorry it was becasue I tried a lot yesterday, and then I forgot to uncomment. I still get the same error though :(

Comment: Ah, I though that was too simple to be true! Have you looked in the logs? Presumably spring fails to create the DAO if it is null.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but when you run the unit tests there should be some kind of console output. Also, have you tried removing the TransactionConfiguration and Transactional annotations from the test? I note you don't have a transaction manager bean declared.

Comment: Yes, @transaction and @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true), was something i added because I saw a lot of other examples on the internet using it, so I thought it should be there, but if I remove them I still get same error. All I get from JUnit console was the stacktrace

Comment: Is it possible that you can show me a very simple example which uses an embedded database like HSQL? and then I can try using that, to see if I get the same error or it is something with my code which is wrong.